# No idea why trigger isn't firing

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

So I'm pretty new to apex and I was practicing some trigger exercises, I was testing a trigger and everything was going well ultil for some reason a DML line that should fire the trigger didn't do so.

```
@isTest static void testContactInfoFieldOnDelete(){
    
    //Test Setup
    Integer count = 2;
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();
    for(Integer i=0; i<3; i++){
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account '+(i+1)); 
        accList.add(acc);
    }
    insert accList;
    
    for(Account a : accList){
        
        for(Integer i=0; i<count; i++){
            Contact con = new Contact(LastName = 'Test Contact '+(i+1), AccountId = a.Id, Is_Valid__c = true);
            conList.add(con);
        }
        count++;
    }  
    insert conList;
    
    List<Contact> newConList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :conList AND (Account.Name = 'Test Account 1' OR Account.Name = 'Test Account 2')];
    List<Contact> newConList2 = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :conList AND Account.Name = 'Test Account 3' LIMIT 3];
       
    
    
    Account plentyAcc = new Account(Name = 'Plenty Account');
    insert plentyAcc;
    
    List<Contact> plentyContacts = new List<Contact>();
    
    for(Integer i=0; i<10; i++){
        Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Test '+i, AccountId = plentyAcc.Id, Is_Valid__c = true);
        plentyContacts.add(c);
    }
    insert plentyContacts;//**Trigger should fire here but it doesn't**
    
    Contact oneCon = [SELECT Id, Name, Is_Valid__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :plentyAcc.Id Limit 1];
    
    //Test
    Test.startTest();
    delete oneCon;//**This should also fire the trigger but it doesn't**
    delete newConList;
    delete newConList2;
    Test.stopTest();
    
    //Verification
    Account acc1 = [SELECT Name, Contact_information__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account 1'];
    Account acc2 = [SELECT Name, Contact_information__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account 2'];
    Account acc3 = [SELECT Name, Contact_information__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account 3'];
    
    
    System.Assert(acc1.Contact_Information__c == 'None');//Works fine
    System.Assert(acc2.Contact_Information__c == 'None');//Works fine
    System.Assert(acc3.Contact_Information__c == 'Scarce');//Works fine
    System.Assert(plentyAcc.Contact_Information__c == 'Plenty');//**The trigger should set the value to Plenty but is null insted**
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please [edit] your post to include the trigger, and describe how you've concluded that the trigger is not firing.

Comment: Can you please also share the code for the trigger?

Comment: I think we'll need to see the trigger in question too. If it is firing on your first contact insert DML, then the thing that immediately pops up into my head is that you perhaps have a static boolean somewhere that is attempting to prevent recursion (but static booleans are unsuited for that task).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to query the plentyAcc again:

```
@isTest static void testContactInfoFieldOnDelete(){
    
    //Test Setup
    Integer count = 2;
    List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();
    List<Contact> conList = new List<Contact>();
    for(Integer i=0; i<3; i++){
        Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test Account '+(i+1)); 
        accList.add(acc);
    }
    insert accList;
    
    for(Account a : accList){
        
        for(Integer i=0; i<count; i++){
            Contact con = new Contact(LastName = 'Test Contact '+(i+1), AccountId = a.Id, Is_Valid__c = true);
            conList.add(con);
        }
        count++;
    }  
    insert conList;
    
    List<Contact> newConList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :conList AND (Account.Name = 'Test Account 1' OR Account.Name = 'Test Account 2')];
    List<Contact> newConList2 = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :conList AND Account.Name = 'Test Account 3' LIMIT 3];
       
    
    
    Account plentyAcc = new Account(Name = 'Plenty Account');
    insert plentyAcc;
    
    List<Contact> plentyContacts = new List<Contact>();
    
    for(Integer i=0; i<10; i++){
        Contact c = new Contact(LastName = 'Test '+i, AccountId = plentyAcc.Id, Is_Valid__c = true);
        plentyContacts.add(c);
    }
    insert plentyContacts;//**Trigger should fire here but it doesn't**
    
    Contact oneCon = [SELECT Id, Name, Is_Valid__c FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :plentyAcc.Id Limit 1];
    
    //Test
    Test.startTest();
    delete oneCon;//**This should also fire the trigger but it doesn't**
    delete newConList;
    delete newConList2;
    Test.stopTest();
    
    //Verification
    Account acc1 = [SELECT Name, Contact_information__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account 1'];
    Account acc2 = [SELECT Name, Contact_information__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account 2'];
    Account acc3 = [SELECT Name, Contact_information__c FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test Account 3'];
    
    
    System.Assert(acc1.Contact_Information__c == 'None');//Works fine
    System.Assert(acc2.Contact_Information__c == 'None');//Works fine
    System.Assert(acc3.Contact_Information__c == 'Scarce');//Works fine
    plentyAcc = [SELECT Contact_Information__c FROM Account WHERE Id =: plentyAcc.Id];
    System.Assert(plentyAcc.Contact_Information__c == 'Plenty');//**The trigger should set the value to Plenty but is null insted**
}
```

Edit:
The trigger fires when you DML, but the record plentyAcc is a local version of it, the trigger won't update your record it just updates  the Id, when you need more values you need to query it from the DB,
Also I saw you said about another trigger is not firing, probably is the same idea, you need to query it either

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm

Comment: It worked thank you, could you explain why it works that way?

Comment: @enzobassadone I'll edit my answer, could you mark it as correct?
But it's basically the trigger fires when you DML, but the record you have is the local version of it, the trigger won't update your record it just returns the Id, when you need more values you need to query it from the DB
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm

Comment: Okay i get it, I couldn't mark your answer as correct before, i did it now, thank you!